# Making an $http.get or $http.jsonp call in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I was given the following code to use to get the data I need, but it is not working for me. What am I doing wrong here. I have tried many things from the Angular.js docs and other stack overflow posts, but nothing has worked for me.

someurl

header: Content-Type = application/json

Pass in the following json:
{
   "userID": "SomeUSER",
   "password": "SomePSWD"
}

Below is the code I am using and it is not working.

```
function getGroup($scope, $http) {
     $http.get('SOMEURL?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&userID=SomeUSER&password=SomePSWD ').
     success(function(data) {
        $scope.group = data;
     });
```

}

Comment: Any errors in your console? Typically, one would use [`$http.jsonp`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) for JSONP requests.

Comment: I am not getting any errors in the console, which is why I am perplexed as to why this is not working for me, yet the backend developer states it is working.

Comment: Backend developer give me the query code he used to make this work, I have plugged in and I am getting an error, stating that it is not a function. I have put it inside and outside of my controller

    function postInitialLoad($scope, $http) {
    var postObject = new Object();
    postObject.userID = "";
    postObject.password = "";
    var headers = new Object();
    headers.Content_Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    $http.post('url', postObject, headers).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.initialLoad = data;
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

this angularjs demo app show how to use http.jsonp

```js
var httpJsonDemoController = angular.module('HttpJsonDemo', []);
httpJsonDemoController.controller('DataController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.jsonp("http://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&name=Waseem%20Hero").
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.name = data.name;
    $scope.salutation = data.salutation;
    $scope.greeting = data.greeting;
    
    
  }).
  error(function (data) {
    $scope.data = "Request failed";
  });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" ng-app="HttpJsonDemo">
  <div ng-controller="DataController">
    <pre ng-model="data">
     {{data}}
    </pre>
    
    <input ng-model='name' />
    {{name}}
    
    <input ng-model='salutation' />
    {{salutation}}
    
    <input ng-model='greeting' />
    {{greeting}}
  </div>
</div>
```